# How to apply a pretrained transformer model from huggingface?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, transformer-model

I am interested in using pre-trained models from Hugging Face for named entity recognition (NER) tasks without further training or testing of the model.

On the [model page of Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT), the only information for reusing the model are as follows:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")
```

I tried the following code, but I am getting a tensor output instead of class labels for each named entity.

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")

text = "my text for named entity recognition here."

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(text, padding=True, truncation=True,max_length=50, add_special_tokens = True)).unsqueeze(0)

with torch.no_grad():
  output = model(input_ids, output_attentions=True)
```

Any suggestions on how to apply the model on a text for NER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the named entity recognition [pipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.TokenClassificationPipeline) (token classification):

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, pipeline,  AutoModelForTokenClassification
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")
nerpipeline = pipeline('ner', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
text = "my text for named entity recognition here."
nerpipeline(text)
```

Output:

```
[{'word': 'my',
  'score': 0.5209763050079346,
  'entity': 'LABEL_0',
  'index': 1,
  'start': 0,
  'end': 2},
 {'word': 'text',
  'score': 0.5161970257759094,
  'entity': 'LABEL_0',
  'index': 2,
  'start': 3,
  'end': 7},
 {'word': 'for',
  'score': 0.5297629237174988,
  'entity': 'LABEL_1',
  'index': 3,
  'start': 8,
  'end': 11},
 {'word': 'named',
  'score': 0.5258920788764954,
  'entity': 'LABEL_1',
  'index': 4,
  'start': 12,
  'end': 17},
 {'word': 'entity',
  'score': 0.5415489673614502,
  'entity': 'LABEL_1',
  'index': 5,
  'start': 18,
  'end': 24},
 {'word': 'recognition',
  'score': 0.5396601557731628,
  'entity': 'LABEL_1',
  'index': 6,
  'start': 25,
  'end': 36},
 {'word': 'here',
  'score': 0.5165827870368958,
  'entity': 'LABEL_0',
  'index': 7,
  'start': 37,
  'end': 41},
 {'word': '.',
  'score': 0.5266348123550415,
  'entity': 'LABEL_0',
  'index': 8,
  'start': 41,
  'end': 42}]
```

Please not that you need to use `AutoModelForTokenClassification` instead of `AutoModel` and that no all models have a trained head for token classification (i.e. you will get random weights for the token classification head).

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting a similar process because I wanted to save the model in addition to using it in a pipeline.

```
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-mnli")

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-mnli")

model_name = "./tmp/"
model.save_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_name)

zss = pipeline('zero-shot-classification', model=model_name, tokenizer=model_name)
zss("I am happy the way I am!!", ["happy", "sad", "netural"])
```

To which results are:

```
{'sequence': 'I am happy the way I am!!',
 'labels': ['happy', 'netural', 'sad'],
 'scores': [0.37897560000419617, 0.311644583940506, 0.30937978625297546]}
```

Posted in Dec 2022: ChatGpt cannot beat this human intelligence!! - My job is still safe...